# Android NDK - NativeActivity vs JNI lib

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

two years ago i developed an Augmented Reality framework on [android-7 (Eclair)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.1.html). Since AR application are computationally intensive task, I developed a JNI c++ library used by a Java activity to render and register the virtual environment. The sensor readings acquired in Java are passed to the underline c++ library to compute the registration of the virtual environment. Tridimensional objects are rendered by a native draw function called from a [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html). This results in a lot of JNI call.

Now I would like to port the application to [android-15(Ice Cream Sandwich)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.3.html). Starting from [android-9(Gingerbread)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html) Android allows to use [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html).

I would like to understand which is the better way to develop an AR application. Since every JNI calls introduce an overhead it would be much better to avoid them. Is it possible using NativeActivity? I didn't find an exaustive guide that explains how NativeActivity works but reading [this document](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Android_GLUT_Wrapper#Android_Events) it seems that it results in a lot of JNI calls anyway. Is there any architectural document that explains how NativeActivity works? Is NativeActivity just a "JNI wrapper" to avoid java code? Concerning performances,are there any advantages using NativeActivity instead of a JNI library as I done before?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NativeActivity will not give a performance boost to your framework. It still uses JNI to communicate with the System, only under the cover.

Moreover, there are good reasons not to use it. If I understand your purpose correctly, you want other applications to take advantage of your code. By forcing them to use NativeActivity you seriously reduce their freedom, and require that they struggle with a less familiar environment. There is a number of limitations with NativeActivity, e.g. it cannot load more than one JNI library.

Finally, I would suggest a completely different direction if you look for optimization of your AR framework: you can use the new [setPreviewTexture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) API.

Comment: Hi Alex. Maybe I wrongly expressed myself. The software I'm developing is not intended to be used by other application. You said that NativeActivity uses JNI to communicate with the system, thus, for example if I read values from sensors, does this result in a JNI call?

Comment: Sensor data is delivered from system service via an IPC mechanism; in some cases, it may be possible to access these binders in native code. But this is not a "public" way, hence there is no guarantee that your code will be forward-compatible. And the performance advantage of bypassing the Java wrapper will be minimal, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it you still are bound to JNI also when using NativeActivity. This class can be used as starting point and encapsulates some functionalities for your convenience but the underlying technology to access native code has not changed and ist still JNI. So in my opinion you only can do some benchmarks to check if NativeActivity is more efficient for some reason (may be the guys at Google do know some hacks that make it faster than your solution).