# Bootstrapping C++ code for Android (NDK and OpenGL)

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

After doing a little research it seems that there are two ways of executing C++ code in Android:

- [Calling C++ code from Java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-gl2), making a single call to pass control to C++.
- [Creating a native activity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity), which seems to give the control directly to C++.

Is there any difference between both of them more than the way to bootstrap C++ code?

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624499/android-ndk-nativeactivity-vs-jni-lib

Comment: I linked to the NativeActivity source code in my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45158014/295004

Comment: Thanks, that other question somehow answers me, sorry for duplicated.